# What wild water plant is this? Is there a domesticated versions?

Tags: identification, wildflowers, water, pond

I saw this plant in a swamp in central Maine, USA.  I think it is a type of wild hyacinth.  Are there domesticated versions? Anyone know how to grow one in a large planter pond?

The spear shaped leaves belong to the plant.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This must be Purple Pickerelweed, Pontaderia cordata.

I've made lots of water 'ponds' but I would invest in great water lilies. I would probably try growing this guy but there is just so much room even in the largest pots. Water lilies shade the water so that the fish I've added don't boil.

[image: larger picture than one that was here before] [Source](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4f/Pontederia_cordata_4_PP.jpg/1200px-Pontederia_cordata_4_PP.jpg)

Comment: The "Potted Pond" link is returning a 400 error (Not found) error.  The other image is so small, it's almost unrecognizable.

Comment: I KNOW!!  That picture is so tiny!  But I tested the other link for potted pond and it worked for me.  Sighs.  Thanks ben!

Comment: Try this as a [larger image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4f/Pontederia_cordata_4_PP.jpg/1200px-Pontederia_cordata_4_PP.jpg).  I alway find that after doing a google search, its easy to click on "images".  At the bottom of each image (as you hover) it tells you the original size.

Comment: Thanks, Ben...having had computers in my life for 40 years, I've gotten lazy or something!

Comment: Hi @Ben! I hope you don't mind, I added the picture you gave stormy directly into her answer. Thanks for providing it!